# EF: object update process is not changing value of one property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

my application has 2 classes: `PaymentMethod` & `Currency` (`Currency` is property of `PaymentMethod`). When my app does update of `PaymentMethod` with new value of `Currency` propery (value already exists in db but it's being assigned to `PaymentMethod`), after `SaveCHanges` method, `Currency` property still contains old value. **WHY?:)**

this is how my application replaces Currency object value:

```
 if (String.Compare(existingPaymentMethod.Currency.Code, mwbepaymentmethod.CurrencyCode, true) !=0)
            {
                var readCurrency = currencyRepo.FindByCode(mwbepaymentmethod.CurrencyCode);

                existingPaymentMethod.Currency = readCurrency;

            }

            paymentMethodRepository.Save(ref existingPaymentMethod);
            return true;
```

`PaymentMethod` & `Currency` classes:

```
public class PaymentMethod : BaseEntity
    {
        public enum MethodTypeEnum
        {
            Creditcard,
            Virtualcard,
            Wallet
        };
        public MethodTypeEnum MethodType { get; set; }
        public int VendorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    }

public class Currency : BaseEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        [Key]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("symbol")]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit method:

```
public override void Edit(MwbePaymentMethod entityToUpdate)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

            //manual update of  properties
            //Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
```

`OnModelCreating` method:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MobileWalletContext>());
           ...
            modelBuilder.Entity<MwbePaymentMethod>().HasRequired(e => e.Currency).WithMany(e => e.PaymentMethods);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

DB context defined by Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<MobileWalletContext>().As<IMwbeDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

**Update 1**:
EF logs shows no currency field update:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MwbeAddress] SET [Street] = @0, [City] = @1, [ZipCode] = @2, [Country] = @3 WHERE ([Id] = @4)
-- @0: 'FFFF12' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: 'GlasgowSSSS' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @2: 'B33 8TH' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @3: 'England' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @4: '2' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 2015-07-13 07:35:48 +02:00
-- Completed in 39 ms with result: 1

UPDATE [dbo].[MwbePaymentMethod] SET [MethodType] = @0, [VendorId] = @1, [Number] = @2, [ExpirationDate] = @3, [Balance] = @4, [IsPending]
= @5, [IsDefault] = @6 WHERE ([Id] = @7)
-- @0: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: '0' (Type = Int32)
-- @2: '4444 4444 4444 4450' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @3: '2015-10-10 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @4: '0' (Type = Double)
-- @5: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
-- @6: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @7: '3' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 2015-07-13 07:35:48 +02:00
-- Completed in 7 ms with result: 1
```

**Why there is not update for `Currency` property?**

Comment: Has it entered the if condition?

Comment: Yes, It entered the if condition

Comment: I will give an answer in 5-6 hours, still waiting for other explanations;). Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting an entity's state (other than `Added`) only affects the entity's *scalar properties*, not its navigation properties, its *associations*.

So you have three options:

#### Option 1

Attach the currency to the context. In your `Edit` method:

```
Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Now EF knows the `Currency` that is assigned to `PaymentMethod`, so it knows the *association* changed, and it will update the foreign key in the database.

But I don't think this is going to work for you just like that. From your problem statement I understand that `currencyRepo` and `paymentMethodRepository` don't share the same context, otherwise you wouldn't have had the problem in the first place (the currency would already be attached). You can't attach an entity to two contexts, so either `currencyRepo`'s context should be disposed at that point, or you should detach the currency from it first. Pretty laborious.

#### Option 2

Let `currencyRepo` and `paymentMethodRepository` (and all repositories for that matter) share the same context instance within one unit of work. This is recommended anyway, not only to solve this problem.

#### Option 3

Don't set the `Currency` property, but add a primitive foreign key property `PaymentMethod.CurrencyId` and modify that property if the currency changes. This is a scalar property, so it will respond to setting `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: I didnt implemented this but it seems to be resonable. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

`DbSet.Attach` is not recursive. You need to attach all the entities involed:

```
public override void Edit(MwbePaymentMethod entityToUpdate)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

            if(entityToUpdate.BillingAddress != null)
            {
              DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate.BillingAddress);
              Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            if(entityToUpdate.Currency != null)
            {
              DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate.Currency);
              Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Currency).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            //manual update of  properties
            //Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.BillingAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //Context.Entry(entityToUpdate.Currency).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
```

Comment: `DbContext.Attach` is not found

Comment: @P.K. oops those should have been `DBSet`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of [foreign key](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) relation in not defined in PaymentMethod class. That need to be specify so specific column will be used to update and in case currency is new then that will be inserted and same code will be saved against currencycode.

```
public class PaymentMethod : BaseEntity
{
    public enum MethodTypeEnum
    {
        Creditcard,
        Virtualcard,
        Wallet
    };
    public MethodTypeEnum MethodType { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyCode {get;set;} //Replace with actual column name

     [ForeignKey("CurrencyCode ")]
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Foreign key for Currency is defined  but with name:FK_dbo.MwbePayment_dbo.MwbeCurrency_Currency_Code. I see it in database.

Comment: This also needs to be specified in code at class level either while onmodelcreation or property level. Onmodelcreation you have specified the relation but not specified property(key) on which the foreign key relation is defined. Please check above code how to specify the foreign key relation.